# insert values in array format for key in object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to convert an array(with email addresses) in to object.
How to insert values in value array for one key?

```js
var list = [
  "john@yahoo.com", "rami@gmail.com",
  "josh@yahoo.com", "bale@gmail.com"
];

(function() {
  var obj1 = {};
  for (var a = 0, b = list.length; b > a; a++) {
    var str = list[a].split("@");
    var arr = [];
    arr.push(str[0]);
    if (!(str[1] in obj1)) {
      obj1[str[1]] = []; //arr.push(str[0])];
    }

    Object.values(obj1[str[1]]).push(str[0])

  };
  console.log(obj1);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

expected output

```
    {
    "gmail.com" : ["a","b","c"],
    "yahoo.com" : ["de","e","f"]
    }
```

I also want to add like

```
    {
    "gmail.com" : [3],//1+1+1
    "yahoo.com" : [4]//1+1+1+1
    }
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: var list = [
  "john@yahoo.com", "rami@gmail.com",
  "josh@yahoo.com", "bale@gmail.com"
];


(function(){
 var obj = {};
   for(var a = 0, b = list.length; b > a; a++){
  var str = list[a].split("@");
  var arr = [];
  arr.push(str[0]);
  if (!(str[1] in obj)){
   obj[str[1]] = arr;
  }
  
  //obj[str[1]].push(str[0]);
  document.write(str[0]);
  document.write('<br>');
 };
console.log(obj);
})();

Answer (score 1):

```js
var list = [
  "john@yahoo.com", "rami@gmail.com",
  "josh@yahoo.com", "bale@gmail.com"
];
obj = {};
list.map(x => x.split('@')[1]).forEach(x => obj[x] = [])
list.forEach(email => obj[email.split('@')[1]].push(email))
console.log(obj)
/*
{
  "yahoo.com": [
"john@yahoo.com",
"josh@yahoo.com"
  ],
  "gmail.com": [
"rami@gmail.com",
"bale@gmail.com"
  ]
}
*/
```

**Explanation**:
Created a blank object `obj`. Then I iterated on `list` and retrieved all the domains by `list.map(x => x.split('@')[1])`.

With domains in hand, I setup-ed the object to have the structure `{ 'yahoo.com': [], 'gmail.com': [] }`

Then I iterated on list again and added the email if domain contained the corresponding part, giving resultant object.

**Edit**:
It can also be done in single iteration this way:

```js
var list = [
  "john@yahoo.com", "rami@gmail.com",
  "josh@yahoo.com", "bale@gmail.com"
]
obj = {}
list.forEach(email => {
  let domain = email.split('@')[1]
  if (!obj[domain]) obj[domain] = []
  if (obj[domain].indexOf(email) < 0) obj[domain].push(email)
})
console.log(obj)
```

Here, I'm iterating on list, extracting the domain, setting up the key with `[]` if it doens't exist and then pushing the email into that. It also makes sure that no duplicate emails are pushed.

Comment: if you'd explain it a little bit, that would be easy for OP to grab and appreciate your effort :)

Comment: @GeorgeBailey sure :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply push the values in the array if the key is found in object otherwise add the array

```js
var list = [
  "john@yahoo.com", "rami@gmail.com",
  "josh@yahoo.com", "bale@gmail.com"
];

(function() {
  var obj1 = {};
  for (var a = 0; a < list.length;  a++) {
    var str = list[a].split("@");
    if(obj1[str[1]]) {
        obj1[str[1]].push(list[a])
    } else {
        obj1[str[1]] = [list[a]]; //arr.push(str[0])];
    }
  };
  console.log(obj1);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct, there is just a minor bug, change your line:

```
Object.values(obj1[str[1]]).push(str[0])
```

To

```
obj1[str[1]].push(list[a]);
```

And it works fine.

```js
var list = [
  "john@yahoo.com", "rami@gmail.com",
  "josh@yahoo.com", "bale@gmail.com"
];

(function() {
  var obj1 = {};
  for (var a = 0, b = list.length; b > a; a++) {
    var str = list[a].split("@");
    var arr = [];
    arr.push(str[0]);
    if (!(str[1] in obj1)) {
      obj1[str[1]] = []; //arr.push(str[0])];
    }

    obj1[str[1]].push(list[a]);

  };
  console.log(obj1);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is typically used to translate `array` data to `object` form.

See below for a practical example

```js
// Emails.
const emailAddresses = ["bale@gmail.com", "john@yahoo.com", "rami@gmail.com","josh@yahoo.com"]

// Group By Domain.
const groupByDomain = addresses => addresses.reduce((acc, email) => {
  const [prefix, domain] = email.split(/@/)
  const exists = acc[domain]
  if (exists) acc[domain].push(email)
  else acc[domain] = [email]
  return acc
}, {})

// Output.
const output = groupByDomain(emailAddresses)

// Proof.
console.log(output)
```